# How to Update dockerfile to set ruby version using rvm

Tags: ruby, docker-compose, rvm

I am new to docker and I am working on a project where we are running application locally in docker container. There is a dockerfile that is pulling base image from amazonlinux. I am using docker-compose for the workflow. I have step to install ruby 2.7.5 using rvm but when I try to run tests using docker-compose `docker-compose run test bundle exec bin/rspec` I get error `Your Ruby version is 3.0.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5`. You can see it is picking up the ruby version from amazon-linux-extras and not rvm
I looked at bunch of threads but no luck so far. Is there any way I can set the ruby version to 2.7.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

What if you installed the version of Ruby that you want using `amazon-linux-extras`?

So instead of:
`RUN amazon-linux-extras enable python3.8 ruby3.0 \`

use:
`RUN amazon-linux-extras enable python3.8 ruby2.7 \`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve the problem:

### Solution

Instead of using this line:

```
RUN rvm use $RUBY_VERSION
```

You should use this:

```
RUN rvm --default use $RUBY_VERSION
```

### Explaination

Because this command will only set the correct RUBY_VERSION in the current shell:

```
RUN rvm use $RUBY_VERSION
```

So when you execute this line,

```
docker-compose run --rm --service-ports --use-aliases -e RACK_ENV=test test bundle exec bin/rspec
```

Another new shell will be create, and it's gonna use the default ruby version which automatically be set as 3.0.3 (when you install it with `RUN amazon-linux-extras enable python3.8 ruby3.0`)

That's the reason why the error is:

```
Your Ruby version is 3.0.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5
```

Hope this helps